# What is the difference between algorithm and passphrase?

Tags: password-based-encryption, algorithm-design

If there is an algorithm securing a document, then why is there also a passphrase when the algorithm is already there?

And if there is a passphrase securing a document, then why do we also use the algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

The cryptographic community has learned from much experience that algorithms to protect data should be public. This leads to much more analysis that helps us be sure that our algorithms are strong.

If the algorithm is public, however, how can it provide any security. For that there must be a secret key that is used within the algorithm. Hence, the need for a passphrase, which is used as the secret. Passphrases are only 1 option, however.

A passphrase by itself is not necessarily sufficient to protect data. Passphrases must be remembered by a human. Therefore, they are much shorter than the document they are protecting, and are not perfectly random.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms, the algorithm is the model of the lock to your house, and the passphrase is the key to that lock.

There are many locks of the same model, each one opened by different key. You can take the lock out of your door, dismantle it, and in general it does not give you any advantage in getting to the neighbour's house. You can take your key and try it on the same lock model at next house, and it will give you no good (same as trying to open a document with a different passphrase).